On invertibility of a real matrix
Given that $A$ is a real 'symmetric' matrix. I need to prove or find a counter example for the statement that $I+iA$ is always invertible, where $I$ is the identity matrix of the order same as that of $A$ (say $n\times n$).
Assuming that $A$ is real, I verified if the rows of $I+iA$ are linearly independent. If I denote the $i^{th}$ row of $A$ by $R_i$,and assume that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} k_j(iR_j+I_j) =0,$$
then I can easily infer that
$$ik_1a_{1j}+ik_2a_{2j}+\dots+k_j(ia_{jj}+1)+\dots+ik_na_{nj}=0,$$
where the above equality is by componentwise comparison. Clearly, as $A$ is real matrix, we must have that
$$k_j = 0.$$
This is true for any $j$, $1\leq j\leq n$. Thus the rows are linearly independent and hence $I+iA$ is invertible.
But nowhere, I used the fact that $A$ is symmetric. Have I missed anything anywhere? Or was the condition 'symmetric' redundant?

I don't see the "componentwise comparison" you claim to use, because you just equate one expression to one number ($0$) in the equation above that statement. Anyhow you did something wrong because for non-symmetric $A$ there is an easy to find $2\times 2$ counterexample. So you must use the symmetry for the invertibility proof.

I have edited. Please check it once. Between, what is the non - symmetric matrix example?

If you know about the rotation group, you will know that rotations have complex eigenvalues $e^{i\phi}$, so we make sure there is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $i$ by rotating over 90 degrees, and then $I+iA$ must have eigenvalue $1+i\cdot i=0$ for that same vector, so it's not invertible (which can then be quickly seen from the determinant). Rotation over 90 degrees by a $2\times 2$ matrix is left as an exercise for the reader...

It is easy to find non-symmetric counterexamples, e.g. $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Yes, thanks Martin R. I now see may flaw in my argument.

I now realize that taken any matrix whose one of the eigen values is $i$, I would end up in the fact that $I+iA$ is non invertible. Like the one given by you or  $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0& -1 \ 1 & 0\end {pmatrix}$.

A quick proof (without consideration of eigenvalues): $(I+iA)(I-iA)=I+{}^tAA$ is symmetric positive-definite, so invertible. Therefore both $I+iA$ and $I-iA$ must be invertible.

For correct proof:
Hint: $I+\mathbf{i}A$ is not invertible iff $\det(I+\mathbf{i}A)=0$. This leads to the thought of eigenvalues. Now think about the eigenvalues of $A$, what eigenvalues can a real symmetric matrix have?
For your proof:

Then I can easily infer that  $k_j(\mathbf{i}a_{j1}+\cdots+1+\cdots+\mathbf{i}a_{jn})=0$.

Do you think this line is correct? (Because you use row vector, you should view it in column perspective!)

Oh! Please check that In have edited my question. Thanks for identifying the mistake

$k_i$ can be complex number, because now you are in $\mathbb{C}$, so you cannot immediately arrive $k_j=0$.

This is the possible error in my argument. Thanks. I shall verify once before affirming its validity.

I now see how silly I was and how easily I missed the argument. The coefficients should have been complex. I had an alternative argument using eigen values that if $x$ is an eigen value of $A$, the $1+ix$ is an eigen value of $iA+I$. Thus, none of these eigen values are zeroes as each $x$ is real and hence, then determinant of $I+iA$ is not zero and hence $I+iA$ must be invertible. But, i wasn't able to find a proper loop hole in my above argument.

Your argument is good, note that since $A$ is symmetric so you can ensure all eigenvalues of $A$ is real. My original method was like saying $\det(I+xA)=0\iff x$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so by above, $\det(I+\mathbf{i}A)$ can never be $0$.

Yes. Agreed! Thanks

Just a small correction that $det(I+xA) = 0$ if and only if $-x$ is an eigen value of $A$.
